# Should I always use Mocks when unit testing for the sake of minimising units in test scope

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, xunit

Consider the following test which confirms that when an object is added to the `HttpContentConatiner` class it's resulting MD5, which is stored on the content container matches the result of serializing and hashing the body content externally (which is how it would be used).

```
[Fact]
public void When_body_added_correctly_MD5_matches_an_external_hash_of_the_same_content()
{
    var contentStub = new object();
    var serializer = new NewtonSoftJsonSerializer();
    var hasher = new Hmac256Hasher();
    var contentContainer = new HttpContentContainer(serializer, hasher);

    contentContainer.AddBody(contentStub);

    Assert.Equal(hasher.Hash(serializer.Serialize(contentStub), "Key"),
                             contentContainer.ContentMD5.Value);

}
```

In this test I use an actual implementation for both the serializer and the hasher as opposed to mocking out these two objects. This now means that the test depends on both the hasher and the serializer working correctly as their implementations have now been pulled into the test scope which I worry may make my tests brittle.

**My Question**
Given the above example, should I mock the serializer and hasher for maintainability purposes or is it ok to depend on external services like this?

**New Code based on Answer:**

```
[Fact]
public void When_a_valid_body_is_added_ContentMD5_Value_is_populated()
{
    var serializerMock = new Mock<ISerializer>();
    serializerMock.Setup(serializer => serializer.Serialize(It.IsAny<object>()))
                  .Returns("serializedContent");

    var hasherMock = new Mock<IHasher>();
    hasherMock.Setup(hasher => hasher.Hash(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string()))
              .Returns("MD5");

    var contentContainer = 
        new HttpContentContainer(serializerMock.Object, hasherMock.Object);

    contentContainer.AddBody(new object());

    Assert.NotEmpty(contentContainer.ContentMD5.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to Mock both Hasher as well as the Serializer.

Reason - Both `Hash` and `Serialize` method of these dependencies could be assumed to perform expected functions, and this can be the expectation of the Mock. A test failure would then indicate the failure of Object under test with certainty.

Comment: That would be a separate test, this test is not to prove that the content is there but to prove that the implementation correctly hashed the content and placed it in the correct property which is used to transfer the hash into a http header on a http request.

Comment: Hmm, your object under test is `HttpContentContainer`. But what you describe involves testing `HttpContentContainer`, `Hmac256Hasher` and `NewtonSoftJsonSerializer`. I wouldn't test actions of 3 classes in one unit test.

Comment: It's not 3 actions. There is one unit to test `HttpContentContainer.ContentMD5.Value`. The only way to populate this read only property is by adding a value via the AddBody method. The test is completely valid, the question pertains to the maintenance of such tests.

Comment: I have marked as correct. I talked to another I know and he agrees with you. I already have a test for hash equality on the hasher so realistically I should just test the value is there. I will update with the new test when it is done. Thanks!